# Why is this source code plotting only two points?

Tags: python, plot

> *Draw 10,000 points on the plane so that both the x and y coordinates of each point are in the range [-1, 1].
>
>   Print the coordinates of only those points which are contained in a circle with radius r0 = 1.0.*

```
def nextRandom(seed):
    m = 233280 # modulus
    a = 9301 # multiplier
    c = 49297 # increment
    x0 = seed # start-value
    return 2*(((a * x0 + c) % m)/m)-1 # between [-1, 1]

N = 10

x = [0]*N
y = [0]*N
p = [0]*N
x0 = 1
y0 = 0
r = 1.0

for i in range(1, N, 1):
    x[i] = nextRandom(x0)
    y[i] = nextRandom(x[i])
    p[i] = x[i] * x[i] + y[i] * y[i] 
    if(p[i]<=r*r):
        print(i, "(", "{0:.2f}, ".format(x[i]), "{0:.2f}".format(y[i]), ")")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

**Output**

```
In [33]: runfile('C:/Users/pc/Desktop/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/pc/Desktop/')
1 ( -0.50,  -0.62 )
2 ( -0.50,  -0.62 )
3 ( -0.50,  -0.62 )
4 ( -0.50,  -0.62 )
5 ( -0.50,  -0.62 )
6 ( -0.50,  -0.62 )
7 ( -0.50,  -0.62 )
8 ( -0.50,  -0.62 )
9 ( -0.50,  -0.62 )
```

[image]

Why is this source code plotting only two points?

**Edit:** modified the code as follows:

```
for i in range(1, N, 1):
    x[i] = nextRandom(x0)
    x0 = x[i] ##<=========================added this line
    y[i] = nextRandom(x[i])
    p[i] = x[i] * x[i] + y[i] * y[i] 
    if(p[i]<=r*r):
        print(i, "(", "{0:.2f}, ".format(x[i]), "{0:.2f}".format(y[i]), ")")
```

**Output**

```
1 ( -0.50,  -0.62 )
2 ( -0.62,  -0.63 )
3 ( -0.63,  -0.63 )
4 ( -0.63,  -0.63 )
5 ( -0.63,  -0.63 )
6 ( -0.63,  -0.63 )
7 ( -0.63,  -0.63 )
8 ( -0.63,  -0.63 )
9 ( -0.63,  -0.63 )
```

[image]

I am not seeing much improvement.

Comment: `for i in range(...): x[i] = nextRandom(x0)` why do you loop over `i` again?

Comment: `x0` always equals `1` while `x[i]` always equals `nextRandom(1)`? If I understand correctly.

Comment: Your function `nextRandom` seems to converge to a fixed point around `-0.627386`, so all of your `x` coordinates will be clustered around that level (as we see in the plot).

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem, u r on the right path. how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: it just means that you found a solution for the equation `x = nextRandom(x)` :-)

Comment: Not really sure. Is there a reason you are trying to write your own random number generator as opposed to using an existing library? Anyway, something is fishy about `nextRandom`. In RNG, seed is usually an integer, and in your case `nextRandom` receives floats after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an issue with the proposed random number generation scheme. Instead of dividing by `m` in the `nextRandom` function, you can generate a bunch of pseudorandom integers between `0` and `m`, then rescale and plot.

```
# output ints!
def nextRandom(seed):
    m = 233280 # modulus
    a = 9301 # multiplier
    c = 49297 # increment
    x0 = seed # start-value
    return ((a * x0 + c) % m)

# generate (hopefully) random ints
m = 233280
# initialize integer arrays to store iterative applications
# of nextRandom. Random seed for x is 0, random seed for y is 1
rx, ry = [0], [1]
for i in range(500):
  rx.append(nextRandom(rx[-1]))
  ry.append(nextRandom(ry[-1]))

# rescale to the 2x2 square around the origin
xs = [2*x/m-1 for x in rx]
ys = [2*y/m-1 for y in ry]
# different colors based on distance to the origin
color = ['red' if x**2 + y**2 < 1 else 'blue' for x, y in zip(xs, ys)]

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(xs, ys, c=color)
```

Results look like this:

[image]

Comment: the source code is too complicated for me to understand.

Comment: Do you have a question about a specific part?

Comment: I understood nothing after `# rescale to the 2x2 square around the origin`.

Comment: `rx, ry = [0], [1]` --- this line is also obscure to me.

Comment: So, this expression occurs in your original `nextRandom` function: `2*(((a * x0 + c) % m)/m)-1`. It can be re-expressed as `2*z/m - 1` where `z` is an integer between `[0, m]`. Then, `2*z/m - 1` takes `z` and maps it onto `[-1,1]` s.t. `0` is mapped to `-1` and `m` is mapped to `1`. The idea is to prepare separate arrays of random integers first, then convert them to floats in `[-1,1]`. A point `(x, y)` is in the unit disk when `x**2 + y**2 <= 1`, which gives us a way to determine the color. The last part is just calling `plt.scatter` with a list of colors for each point.