# Why are the random numbers not properly scattered?

Tags: c#, random

My task is to implement a random number generator using LCG algorithm.

The task is to generate 1000 axes (x,y) between [-1, 1] and print them on a pane.
If the point is inside the circle of radius 1.0, it will be printed as Red.
Otherwise, Blue.

I used the parameters suggested by [Numerical Recipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use) suggested in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4sYawx70iP4&t=588s). I am following the coding style used [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60664522/159072).

I am using [ZedGraph](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5431/A-flexible-charting-library-for-NET) to show my plots.

Why are the random numbers not properly scattered on the pane?
And, where are the blue points?

**Random number generator class:**

```
class MyRandom
{
    long m = 4294967296;// modulus
    long a = 1664525; // multiplier
    long c = 1013904223; // increment
    public long nextRandomInt(long seed)
    {
        return (((a * seed + c) % m));
    }

    private double nextRandomDouble(long seed)
    {
        return (2 * (nextRandomInt(seed) / m)) - 1;
    }

    public double nextRandomDouble(double seed)
    {
        double new_seed = seed + 1.0;
        new_seed = new_seed / 2.0;
        new_seed = new_seed * m;

        long long_seed = Convert.ToInt64(new_seed);

        double new_s = nextRandomInt(long_seed);
        new_s = new_s / m;
        new_s = new_s * 2;
        new_s = new_s - 1;

        return new_s;
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

Additional Source Code:

**Driver Program:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int N = 1000;
        double radius = 1.0;

        List<double> rx = new List<double>(); rx.Add(0.0);            
        List<double> ry = new List<double>(); ry.Add(1.0);

        MyRandom r = new MyRandom();

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            double x = r.nextRandomDouble(rx[rx.Count - 1]);
            double y = r.nextRandomDouble(ry[ry.Count - 1]);

            rx.Add(x);
            ry.Add(y);
        }

        PlotForm form = new PlotForm();
        ZedGraphControl zgControl = form.ZedGrapgControl;

        //// get a reference to the GraphPane
        GraphPane gPane = zgControl.GraphPane;
        gPane.Title.Text = "Random Numbers";
        gPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Linear;

        PointPairList insideCircleList = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList outsideCircleList = new PointPairList();

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            double x = rx[i];
            double y = ry[i];

            if ((x * x + y * y) < radius)
            {
                insideCircleList.Add(x, y);
            }
            else
            {
                outsideCircleList.Add(x, y);
            }
        }

        LineItem redCurve = gPane.AddCurve("Inside", insideCircleList, Color.Red, SymbolType.Circle);
        redCurve.Line.IsVisible = false;
        redCurve.Symbol.Fill.Type = FillType.Solid;

        LineItem blueCurve = gPane.AddCurve("Outside", outsideCircleList, Color.Blue, SymbolType.Circle);
        blueCurve.Line.IsVisible = false;

        zgControl.AxisChange();

        form.ShowDialog();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**WinForms Code:**

```
public partial class PlotForm : Form
{
    public ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl ZedGrapgControl { get; set; }
    public PlotForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ZedGrapgControl = this.zgc;
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you need to explain why you are not using built-in PRNG support. Does your question specifically need an answer for the PRNG you've implemented? Or is _any_ means of obtaining well-distributed random numbers sufficient? Second, you need to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem. Surely the correlative issue in your example could be reproduced with a simpler scenario. And in any case, the example should not require the use of irrelevant external libraries.

Comment: In the meantime, I will suggest that you work harder to encapsulate the PRNG logic. In particular, making the caller the source of the seed value couples the caller with the implementation in a way that can easily introduce bugs, and in any case will make it much harder to verify correct implementation.

Comment: I doubt you will find anyone qualified to attempt to debug your code willing to do so until you've provided a better code example.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, edited. Is that good enough?

Comment: Your edit has not changed the code example in any material way. My suggestion about encapsulation was a) for your benefit, not necessarily needed for a proper [mcve], and b) wasn't even followed anyway (yes, you moved the code to a separate class, but the seed value is still being passed in with each call). Please read [mcve] so that you understand what kind of code example is required here on Stack Overflow. See also [ask], and especially the other articles linked at the bottom of that page, for more advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`seed` should not be a parameter of the random function, but a field within a random class. You set it once, and it changes with every random call.

But to answer your question, you don't save `new_seed` anywhere. It has to be saved so that it can be used in the next random call. So, your seed is just incremented by one in every new call, and this makes the graph a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular C# Random class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8), it doesn't seem worth it to "roll your own" in this case.

I think this will be good enough for your purpose.

> The current implementation of the Random class is based on a modified
>   version of Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator
>   algorithm.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

If that doesn't meet your requirements you can look into:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.8